# hyperlink in php search result?

Tags: php

i am new to php
How do i make my search result,ie title is show such that is hyper link to a page?
i have already iput a  url column in the table in phpmyadmin

the php code is shown below

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("books",$connect) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookinfo";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchbox']);

$sql .= " WHERE title = '{$search_term}'";
$sql .= " OR author = '{$search_term}'";

}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


?>
<form name="searchform" method="POST" >
Search:<input type="text" name="searchbox" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search book" />
</form>
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Author</td>
    <td>Price</td>


</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>   
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>

</tr>
<?php }
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: With `echo "<a href=\"$link\">$link</a>";` or something. Show what you've tried, sample database content, the resulting output, and explain how it misbehaves or differs from your expectations,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperlinks are made with the `a` (or "anchor") tag in HTML.  Simply include one in your output:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i have been searching and trying for hours.
i just replace the above code with td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
and it works!

Comment: Model answer :) And if you've got short tags enabled, you can also simplify this to <td><a href="<?=$row['url']?>"><?=$row['title']?></a></td>